# magento 2 / Out of memory error

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i am trying to get orders collection but getting error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 887095296) (tried to
>   allocate 803225600 bytes)

I have 2GB of *memory_limit*. I am getting error when calling **orders** function. Here is my code for getting orders:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtName\Block;

class Add extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $_orderConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function orders($customerId) {
        $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => 'pending']
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            '5'
        )->load();

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you set 2GB in `memory_limit` in PHP, there is still chance memory will run out. Adding swap space may help, as stated in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/out-of-memory.html). By the way, how many orders do you have?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I have 10 orders just for test and 1 for specified customer.

Comment: I have ever got the same problem. I solved that problem by restarting my webserver (I use Apache 2.4.23) and clean/flush magento2 cache (via console/cmd).